# Django URL, pass parameters in URL

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to create url like:

/api/foodfeeds/?keywords=BURGER,teste&mood=happy&location=2323,7767.323&price=2

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/foodfeed/(?P<keywords>[0-9.a-z, ]+)/(?P<mood>[0-9.a-z, ]+)/(?P<location>[0-9]+)/(?P<price>[0-9]+)/$', backend_views.FoodfeedList.as_view()),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**views.py**

```
class FoodfeedList(APIView):
    # permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    def get(self,request,keywords,mood,location,price):
        print(request.GET['keywords'])
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting? What is that you are expecting?

Comment: You can't pass the paramaters like that. Those are query parameters and are not specified in the `url`. You should implement the logic in `views.py` and check the query parameters there.

Comment: what will be the good way to pass parameters ?

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params

Answer (score 4):

As @Umair said, you're passing those keys as ***URL query parameters***, so you don't have to mention it in **`URLPATTERNS`**

In your case, to get the data you're passing through the URL, follow the below code snippet

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
                  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                  url(r'^api/foodfeed/', backend_views.FoodfeedList.as_view()),
              ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)


#views.py
class FoodfeedList(APIView):
    # permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    def get(self, request):
        print(request.GET) # print all url params
        print(request.GET['keywords'])
        print(request.GET['mood'])
        # etc
```

Answer (score 2):

Those `keywords`, `mood`, `location`, etc are `query params` you should not include those in url, rather you should access them via `request.query_params`

Reference : http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params